# jsf button close browser page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces, and a trying to see if I can have  on the thank you page I have so that if clicked by user, it will simply close the browser page. the page is .xhtml if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

how about this (seems to work in Chrome/IE/Opera not FF):

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" onclick="window.close()"></p:commandButton>
```

or

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" onclick="window.opener=null;window.open('','_self');window.close();"></p:commandButton>
```

it seems that no really possible to close window in FF (at least not without modifying the FF configs locally) there are plenty of suggestions on how to close the window in FF, but none of them really works...

[closing window in firefox](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=closing%20window%20in%20firefox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Comment: that doesn't work...it just reload i think or submit something but nothing is happening...

Comment: Yes :( Ive only tested on firefox

Comment: type="button" would be needed to define the button as a push button, no ajax/non-ajax submit.

Comment: I have this problem too, but my page reloads and does not close. tested in chrome.

Comment: @cassiafreitas, then post a new question with all the relevant info